# append attribute to resurce from resource::make in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-resource

I am trying to build a laravel api route to return users data. I got some data stored in txt file. To avoid accessing txt many times, the txt file is read in controller but not in resource.
However, after I use `UserResource::make($user)` and `UserResource::collection($user)`, I cannot assign some other attributes to the return of resource.

I want to do something like this:

```
$newAttr = $myFileReader->read(abc.txt) //search and return the attr I need
$user_rsc = UserResource::make($user);
$user_rsc['newAttr'] = $newAttr;
return $user_rsc; // the result does not have the newAttr in my case
```

Is it possible to append attribute after resource::make?

I had try this `$user_rsc->additional(['tag' => "haha"]);` before, it does not work in my case.

Comment: Please used the "additional" method like $user_rsc->additional(['newAttr' => $newAttr]);

Comment: you have to verify this : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data-when-constructing-resources

Comment: @HiteshPadhara I try it before and it does not work for me.

Comment: Please try with : $user_rsc = $user_rsc->with('newAttr', $newAttr); or return UserResource::make($user)->merge(['newAttr' => $newAttr]);   Let me know this will work or not.

Comment: You just want to return `newAttr ` with the user_rsc **or** to store it in database at time of `UserResource::make($user);` ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo for return the value only

Comment: @HiteshPadhara For with(), it returns the origin user and the newAttr did not append to it. For merge(), the merge function is undefined. Am I need to modify  my resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the object returned from `UserResource::make() is immutable`. And I cannot solve it by `additional()` and `with()`. Finally, I decide to use a bad practice to solve it temporarily:

Here is the solution:

```
$user_rsc = UserResource::make($user)->toArray($request);
$user_rsc['tag'] = $tags;
```

The idea is to convert the resource to array and append new attribute.
I am pretty sure this is not a proper way.

Comment: You can use **Eloquent: Mutators & Casting** for this.